# How to plot multiple bar charts in python

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, plot, bar-chart, seaborn

My intention is to re-create the below graph using matplotlib and seaborn:

[image]

The problem is that, The way I'm doing it I only get the graphs for Mediation. My current graph is shown below:

[image]

my code is shown below:

```
def save_bar_chart(title):
    filename = "response_time_summary_" + str(message_size) + "_" + str(backend_delay) + "ms.png"
    print("Creating chart: " + title + ", File name: " + filename)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    fig.set_size_inches(11, 8)

    df_results = df.loc[(df['Message Size (Bytes)'] == message_size) & (df['Back-end Service Delay (ms)'] == backend_delay)]

    df_results = df_results[
        ['Message Size (Bytes)', 'Concurrent Users', '90th Percentile of Response Time (ms)', '95th Percentile of Response Time (ms)',
         '99th Percentile of Response Time (ms)']]

    df_results = df_results.set_index(['Message Size (Bytes)', 'Concurrent Users']).stack().reset_index().rename(
        columns={'level_2': 'Summary', 0: 'Response Time (ms)'})

    sns.barplot(x='Concurrent Users', y='Response Time (ms)', hue='Summary', data=df_results, ci=None)
    ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(tkr.FuncFormatter(lambda y, p: "{:,}".format(y)))
    plt.suptitle(title)
    plt.legend(loc=2, frameon=True, title="Response Time Summary")
    plt.show()
    plt.savefig(filename)
    plt.clf()
    plt.close(fig)
```

The data looks like this:

[image]

**This [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wg0VttCnCeU17v5dxlwP8Yyu7yTCFOuc1VmTOtPLeG4/edit?usp=sharing) contains the data**

Answer (score 0):

You can reshape your DataFrame using melt

```
df_ = df[['Concurrent Users', '90th Percentile of Response Time (ms)',
     '95th Percentile of Response Time (ms)', '98th Percentile of Response Time (ms)',
     '99th Percentile of Response Time (ms)', '99.9th Percentile of Response Time (ms)']].melt('Concurrent Users')
```

and use the `hue` parameter in `barplot`

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sns.barplot(x='Concurrent Users', y='value', hue=0, data=df_, ax=ax)
```

The new DataFrame `df_` looks like this:

```
   Concurrent Users                                      0  value
0                50  90th Percentile of Response Time (ms)     26
1               100  90th Percentile of Response Time (ms)     51
2               200  90th Percentile of Response Time (ms)    105
3               300  90th Percentile of Response Time (ms)    158
4               500  90th Percentile of Response Time (ms)    243
```

And has these `dtypes`

```
Concurrent Users     int64
0                   object
value                int64
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this gives an error when executing line : sns.barplot(x='Concurrent Users', y='value', hue=0, data=df_, ax=ax). The error says : TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: What's the output of `df_.dtypes`?

Comment: I did : df_results = df_results[
        [ 'Concurrent Users', '90th Percentile of Response Time (ms)', '95th Percentile of Response Time (ms)',
         '99th Percentile of Response Time (ms)']].melt('Concurrent Users') and it gave data type as series but when I  assign the result to "df_" it says object

Comment: Sorry, but you did not answer my question and `df_` can not be a `Series`.

Comment: Sorry it says DataFrame

Comment: Please see my edits.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189542/discussion-between-joergvanaken-and-suleka-28).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
df_out = df.set_index(['Concurrent Users','Scenario Name']).filter(like='Percentile').unstack()
df_out.columns = [f'{i} - {j}' for i, j in df_out.columns]
df_out.plot.bar(figsize=(15,10))
```

Output:

[image]